# DATE concept in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

i have created VB.net project.In that i have two textbox,and two buttons

- button1-->submit
- button2-->Duedate
- textbox1 contain the current date

My constraints is if i click button2(Duedate) than add 30 days to textbox1 date and assign that value into textbox2.
How to achieve this?

I want the result like  as folloes

```
If I give textbox1 = 12/12/2009
than
I click Duedate: textbox2.text =11/1/2010
```

Is it possible.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @megala - 54 questions and only 28% have acceptable answers? People see this and do not want to answer your questions. Perhaps take the time to go over your questions and mark more answers as accepted?

Answer (score 3):

Like so:

```
Dim d As Date
If DateTime.TryParse(textbox1.Text, d) Then
  textbox2.Text = d.AddDays(30).ToShortDateString()
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Your button text should be something like:

```
    If IsDate(TextBox1.Text) Then
        Dim newdate As Date = CDate(TextBox1.Text)
        newdate = newdate.AddDays(30)
        Dim myDateFormat As String = "dd/MM/yyyy" //or whatever
        DueDateTExtbox2.Text = newdate.ToString(myDateFormat)
    End If
```

Comment: I tried
i gave textbox1.text=27/12/2009
But it shows error the following line
Dim newdate As Date = CDate(TextBox1.Text)
Error message:
Conversion from String 27/12/2010 to  date not valid

Answer (score 0):

```
        'test data
    Dim dStr As String = "25/12/2009"
    Dim d, d30 As DateTime
    Dim invC As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("") 'invariant culture
    If DateTime.TryParseExact(dStr, "dd/M/yyyy", _
                              invC, _
                              Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces _
                              Or Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, d) Then
        d30 = d.AddDays(30)
    End If
```